# Django server crashes when accessing webcam with opencv

Tags: django, python-2.7, opencv

So I  found out that everything works fine when I remove cv2.imshow("Face",img) from the code but when it is used, the server crashes due to some reason. The code runs perfectly when run as a plain script excluding django code. Can anyone tell me why is this happening and the possible solution? thanks

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import cv2
import numpy as np
from settings import BASE_DIR
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def create_dataset(request):
    userId = request.POST['userId']
    faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier(BASE_DIR+'/ml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    id = userId
    sampleNum = 0
    while(True):
        ret, img = cam.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            sampleNum = sampleNum+1
            cv2.imwrite(BASE_DIR+'/ml/dataset/user.'+str(id)+'.'+str(sampleNum)+'.jpg', gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)
            cv2.waitKey(500)

        cv2.imshow("Face",img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
        if(sampleNum>35):
            break

    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

return redirect('/')
```

---

Here is the stack trace

- Process:               python2.7 [12301]
- Path:                  /Users/USER/*/python
- Identifier:            python2.7
- Crashed Thread:        3
- Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
- Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
- Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
- Application Specific Information:
- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+[NSUndoManager(NSInternal) _endTopLevelGroupings] is only safe to invoke on the main thread.'
  abort() called
  terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
- Application Specific Backtrace 1:
  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb40d32cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
  1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffc8eeb48d objc_exception_throw + 48
  2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffb40d8042 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
  3   Foundation                          0x00007fffb5b20be0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
  4   Foundation                          0x00007fffb5aab093 +[NSUndoManager(NSPrivate) _endTopLevelGroupings] + 170
  5   AppKit                              0x00007fffb1b374ed -[NSApplication run] + 1200
  6   QtGui                               0x00000001141fbe44 _ZN26QEventDispatcherMacPrivate22ensureNSAppInitializedEv + 128
  7   QtGui                               0x00000001141fb5ff _ZN19QEventDispatcherMac13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 777
  8   QtCore                              0x0000000114e5dfdc _ZN16QCoreApplication13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 80
  9   cv2.so                              0x000000010e9cf53f cvWaitKey + 207
  10  cv2.so                              0x000000010e9cfba7 _ZN11GuiReceiver12createWindowE7QStringi + 359
  11  cv2.so                              0x000000010e9cf9a0 cvNamedWindow + 528
  12  cv2.so                              0x000000010e9d207a _ZN11GuiReceiver9showImageE7QStringPv + 170
  13  cv2.so                              0x000000010e9d1f49 cvShowImage + 553
  14  cv2.so                              0x000000010e9cab55 _ZN2cv6imshowERKNS_6StringERKNS_11_InputArrayE + 581
  15  cv2.so                              0x000000010dee3454 _ZL18pyopencv_cv_imshowP7_objectS0_S0_ + 404
  16  libpython2.7.dylib                  0x000000010b9598f4 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 22980

---

solved the problem with ** python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload ** command. Apparently the whole process had to run through main thread for some reason.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or log from Django side? That often holds valuable clues.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I've updated the stack trace too.

Answer (score 2):

What you appear to have here is a mismatch between the expectations of a headless web server environment and code that expects access to screen. Said another way, Web server request handlers and blocking UI code aren't generally compatible.

What you might be able to do here is to remove the `cv2.waitKey` and `cv2.imshow` calls, and instead save an additional image after you've done the `cv2.rectangle` calls, passing that image name to the template. In the template, use that name in as the part of the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element. Then add an additional request handler to return the annotated image to the browser.

Comment: Thank you! solved the problem with ** python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload ** command. Apparently the whole process had to run through main thread for some reason.